# How to use an image texture which contains multiple elements?

Tags: texturing, image

I am looking at different grass textures which I usually import as a plane.
However I have found [this texture](https://www.textures.com/download/3DAtlas0077/133388) which contains **multiple** chunks of grass and I am wondering how can I split those into multiple planes to use them separately ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a plane, give it the image as material (plug the *Image Texture* into the *Principled BSDF*), switch to *Edit* mode, cut the plane with the knife tool:

[image]

Then go into the *Mesh* panel > *Split > Faces by Edges*:

[image]

At last, select all and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > By Loose Parts*:

[image]

If you need to correct the shape of the mesh without deforming the image, enable the *Correct Face Attributes* option:

[image]

[image]